# php htaccess rewrite helpME please

Tags: php, .htaccess, variables, get, url-rewriting

there.
I'm new with htaccess.
Please help me 2 write url rewrite to these links

Url's:

- url - index.php?page=news
- url - index.php?page=users&nickname=name
- url - index.php?cat=Category
- url - index.php?cat=Category&seo-link=Title
- url - index.php?cat=Category&sub_cat=SubCategory
- url - index.php?cat=Category&sub_cat=SubCategory&seo-link=Title
- url - index.php?page=gallery&album=albumName
- url - index.php?page=gallery&album=albumName&image=imageName

Need to be Url's:

- page.com/news/
- page.com/user/nickname/
- page.com/it-news/
- page.com/it-news/old/title/
- page.com/it-news/title/

Something like that.
Thanks, a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make a file in your main directory and put this code in it. Call the file `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)?/?$    index.php?cat=$1&page=$2    [NC,L]
```

The brackets with the numbers and letters is what is allowed, what is in the brackets will then go to the cat= where `$1` is variable in your url. The second bracket will go to where the `$2` is. So for example if you type `/it-news` into your browser, it would actually load `index.php?cat=it-news&page=` and if you type in `/it-news/datahere` it would actually load `index.php?cta=it-news&page=datahere`. Each of the ? in the code means that what lies before it does not need to be there, or an be there once or no times. The () are call backs in order $1 $2 $3

Hope this helps!

Comment: this doesn't work on my end :(

Comment: what happens when you try it?

Comment: I wrote it wrong, one sec, look at my code again, sorry

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. Sorry, should work now

Comment: this one works hope that what he wanted...

Comment: i'm here to help other people :P anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

An Example

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^news/?$    index.php?cat=news    [NC,L]
```

Please Note! you most have modRewrite Active on Apache
you can further read [here](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Comment: This only covers one of his rules he would need.